# App crashing when UIAlertController is displayed

Tags: uialertview

I have just changed my deployment target from iOS 8 to 7 so I am testing my app on iOS 7 for the first time.

I am having an issue with the UIAlertController crashing my app when it is called. It works absolutely fine on iOS 8 however doesn't work at all on iOS 7.

Here is the code I am using:

```
    @IBAction func resetAllButton(sender : AnyObject) {
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Start Over", message: "Are you sure you want to start over? This will erase your budget and all transactions.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "I'm sure!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:{ (ACTION :UIAlertAction!)in
        self.resetView()
        }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`UIAlertController` is only available on iOS 8 or higher. You need to use a [`UIAlertView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html) to present the alert on iOS 7.